# Alternatives in pandas pct_change

Tags: pandas

I'm attempting to utilize pandas pct_change as a running percent change. i.e. each row as a percent change of the first row. As it's used, pct_change gives NAs until the period is met (say 10).  Is there a way to override the NAs? (not looking for the fill method as that fills empty data in the set, I'm looking to fill NAs within the pct_change data itself)

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: import datetime as dt

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame([2,2.5,3.5,5],[dt.date(2020,8,1),dt.date(2020,8,2),dt.date(2020,8,3),dt.date(2020,8,4)])

In [5]: df[1] = df[0].pct_change(3)

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
              0    1
2020-08-01  2.0  NaN
2020-08-02  2.5  NaN
2020-08-03  3.5  NaN
2020-08-04  5.0  1.5
```

I would like:

8-2 to fill as .25 -- (2.5-2)/2 &

8-3 to fill as .75 -- (3.5-2)/2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just copy value from first row into a temporary column,  then do calculation yourself.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([2,2.5,3.5,5],[dt.date(2020,8,1),dt.date(2020,8,2),dt.date(2020,8,3),dt.date(2020,8,4)])
df = df.assign(
    first=df.iloc[0,0],
    pct_cng=lambda dfa: abs(dfa[0] - dfa["first"])/2
).drop("first", axis=1)
```

**output**

```
              0  pct_cng
2020-08-01  2.0     0.00
2020-08-02  2.5     0.25
2020-08-03  3.5     0.75
2020-08-04  5.0     1.50
```